# Combinations with different repetitions allowed

Tags: combinations

Having a set of n letters {A, B, C, ...} how it's possible to calculate the number of different combinations of k elements , if the number of repetitions allowed for each letter is limited to a number, different for each letter?

E.g.

- Letters => {A, B, C, D}
- k = 10
- A can be repeated up to 2 times, B can be repeated up to 4 times, C can be repeated up to 5 times, D can be repeated 3 times?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Give a few examples of the specific *objects* themselves that you are trying to count.  Given your setup in your post, are you counting things like (AA)(BBB)(CCCCC) where all letters must appear in alphabetical order or are you counting ABACCCCCBB as being "different" than AABBBCCCCC?

Comment: @JMoravitz the alphabetical order is not important, but ABACCCCCBB it's considered different from AABBBCCCCC

Comment: Why are they considered different?  They both have two A's, three B's, and five C's?  The word "combinations" has some implications that you seem to not be aware of.  So then, your question seems to actually be about the number of *strings* of length $k$ using $n$ available characters with maximum amounts $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$ respectively.

Comment: Sorry @JMoravitz, you're right and I was wrong in my last comment, so ABACCCCCBB is equivalent to AABBBCCCCC (they're considered equal)

Comment: In that case then it is an exact duplicate of the earlier linked question, the only differences being flavor and labels.  The question of counting strings is *much* more tedious, and many approaches will feel almost like brute force.  One such approach being breaking down based on the exact number of each letter used.